Bluetooth headphones disconnect only after music starts to play
I have Sennheiser 350BT headphones which I paired to my machine (Ubuntu 22).
When I start to play music, after about 2 minutes the headphones will disconnect.
Here are the relevant results of grep blue /var/log/syslog:
Apr 15 21:31:52 gyro bluetoothd[7143]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:handle_unanswered_req() No reply to Suspend request
Apr 15 21:31:52 gyro bluetoothd[7143]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Apr 15 21:31:54 gyro bluetoothd[7143]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1B_66_C7_E2_0F/sep1/fd6: fd(41) ready
Apr 15 21:31:54 gyro pulseaudio[1488]: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1B_66_C7_E2_0F/sep1/fd6 Volume failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property 'Volume'
Apr 15 21:32:00 gyro ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1735]: unable to update icon for blueman
Apr 15 21:32:13 gyro ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1735]: unable to update icon for blueman
Apr 15 21:32:43 gyro ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1735]: unable to update icon for blueman
Apr 15 21:33:48 gyro ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1735]: unable to update icon for blueman
Apr 15 21:34:04 gyro ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1735]: unable to update icon for blueman
Apr 15 21:34:18 gyro ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1735]: unable to update icon for blueman
Apr 15 21:34:48 gyro ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1735]: unable to update icon for blueman
Apr 15 21:34:50 gyro bluetoothd[7143]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
Apr 15 21:34:56 gyro bluetoothd[7143]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:handle_unanswered_req() No reply to Suspend request
Apr 15 21:34:56 gyro pulseaudio[1488]: Transport Acquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1B_66_C7_E2_0F/sep1/fd6 (Input/output error)
Apr 15 21:34:56 gyro bluetoothd[7143]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Apr 15 21:34:58 gyro bluetoothd[7143]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1B_66_C7_E2_0F/sep1/fd7: fd(41) ready
Apr 15 21:34:58 gyro pulseaudio[1488]: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1B_66_C7_E2_0F/sep1/fd7 Volume failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property 'Volume'

This really seem to only happen if I play something (waited 10~ minutes without playing anything to test this).
I'm not sure how to fix this and would welcome any help.
